# .htaccess rewrite conflict issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Please I have a problem with this .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdomain

#Make sure it's an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#Make sure its a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This .htaccess help me access this url http://domain.com/subdomain/index.php?mode=page as http://domain.com/subdomain/page/

Now I want to access this url http://domain.com/subdomain/checkout.php as http://domain.com/subdomain/checkout/ But this not working online, but when I test on localhost all work fine.

Can I do any changes on .htaccess to resolve this ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't have disabled `MultiViews` options then it should work when you go to `/subdomain/checkout` (automatically resolved as `checkout.php`)

Comment: I posted all code in .htaccess what should I do to verify `MultiViews` status ?

Comment: If it's not in your htaccess, it could be in apache config but it seems the problem comes from elsewhere. I think `/subdomain/checkout/` is rewritten to `index.php?mode=checkout` (last rule)

Comment: Exactly, that why I'm asking if I should add something to my .htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a moment of luck, I solved this :)

Before I was trying to specify something special to checkout.php in .htaccess like that

```
RewriteRule checkout/ checkout.php
```

In fact, this was the solution, but instead of putting it after previous code "in my question", I put it directly after this line

```
RewriteBase /subdomain
```